# Correct JSON API Request Godaddy Domain Purchase

Tags: json, rest, godaddy-api

I already have a JSON but the api always bring me:

```
{
  "code": "INVALID_AGREEMENT_KEYS",
  "message": "End-user must read and consent to all of the following legal agreements: DNPA",
  "name": "ApiError"
}
```

I tried with:

```
{  
   "url": "http://www.secureserver.net/agreements/ShowDoc.aspx?pageid=reg_sa&pl_id=1",
   "agreementKey": "DNRA",
   "content": "..content.."
}
```

but it  gives me this:

```
{
  "message": "request entity too large",
  "expected": 268149,
  "length": 268149,
  "limit": 102400,
  "type": "entity.too.large"
}
```

The Json is:

```
{
  "domain": "sistemasolutions.com",
  "consent": {
     "agreementKeys": [
      "DNRA"
    ],
    "agreedBy": "Luis Gonzalez",
    "agreedAt": "2016-12-24T07:37:43+00:00"
  },
  "period": 1,
  "nameServers": [
    " "
  ],
  "renewAuto": true,
  "privacy": false,
  "contactRegistrant": {
    "nameFirst": "Luis",
    "nameMiddle": "",
    "nameLast": "Gonzalez",
    "organization": "Inquid",
    "jobTitle": "CEO",
    "email": "contact@inquid.co",
    "phone": "4491010645",
    "fax": " ",
    "addressMailing": {
      "address1": "1501 India Street",
      "address2": " ",
      "city": "San Diego",
      "state": "California",
      "postalCode": "92101",
      "country": "US"
    }
  },
  "contactAdmin": {
    "nameFirst": "Luis",
    "nameMiddle": "",
    "nameLast": "Gonzalez",
    "organization": "Inquid",
    "jobTitle": "CEO",
    "email": "contact@inquid.co",
    "phone": "+1.7737374427",
    "fax": " ",
    "addressMailing": {
      "address1": "1501 India Street",
      "address2": " ",
      "city": "San Diego",
      "state": "California",
      "postalCode": "92101",
      "country": "US"
    }
  },
  "contactTech": {
    "nameFirst": "Luis",
    "nameMiddle": "",
    "nameLast": "Gonzalez",
    "organization": "Inquid",
    "jobTitle": "CEO",
    "email": "contact@inquid.co",
    "phone": "+1.7737374427",
    "fax": " ",
    "addressMailing": {
      "address1": "1501 India Street",
      "address2": " ",
      "city": "San Diego",
      "state": "California",
      "postalCode": "92101",
      "country": "US"
    }
  },
  "contactBilling": {
    "nameFirst": "Luis",
    "nameMiddle": "",
    "nameLast": "Gonzalez",
    "organization": "Inquid",
    "jobTitle": "CEO",
    "email": "contact@inquid.co",
    "phone": "+1.7737374427",
    "fax": " ",
    "addressMailing": {
      "address1": "1501 India Street",
      "address2": " ",
      "city": "San Diego",
      "state": "California",
      "postalCode": "92101",
      "country": "US"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add what you will try to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my json were incorrect and the way to check how it should be is to use the POST method:
/v1/domains/purchase/validate
in:
https://api.godaddy.com/v1/domains/purchase/validate

That is how I realised the wrong part was the date format

```
"consent": {
     "agreementKeys": [
      "DNRA"
    ],
    "agreedBy": "Luis Gonzalez",
    "agreedAt": "2016-12-24T07:37:43+00:00"
  },
```

which should be:

```
"consent": {
     "agreementKeys":["DNRA"],
    "agreedBy": "Luis Gonzalez",
    "agreedAt": "2016-09-22T14:01:54.9571247Z"
  },
```

And also phone formats were incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this line is actually rather than formatting, it wants you to read and approve the contract when you set privacy true, since there is no endpoint in it, if you set privacy false, the problem will be solved.